# Limit results of NSFetchedResultsController in UITableView

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

This will probably seem silly, but I cannot figure out how too set the limit of a NSFetchedResultsController. Even when setting the fetchLimit I still get all records. I want to set the limit to 1 so that in "freemium" mode there is only one option, but when the app is unlocked you get the full table

```objective-c
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Poem"];
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
fetchRequest.resultType = NSManagedObjectResultType;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO selector:nil]];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1;
// setup my predicate
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:kDataContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

I also have a method to fetch data. This method is intended to be run at load and when the user unlocks the full version of the app.

```objective-c
- (void)refetchData {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    // handle error

    [self.documentsTable reloadData];
}
```

I've experimented with setting the UITableView numberOfRowsInSection to return 1, but then I get warning logs. Plus, I feel that is cheating. I'd like to keep the app data-driven.

edit:
I might also add that I'm using AFIncrementalStore to sync my data with a web service. I'm not sure if this would cause any problems.

Comment: The problem (I think) is that the fetch request is used only for the initial fetch, but not for the change tracking of the FRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hard-coding the -numberOfRowsInSection to return 1 if needed. It still fetches everything, really not sure what I can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that fetchLimit is not working here. You can try setting fetchBatchSize to 1 alongside setting fetchLimit, which should work.

Comment: Really strange. I think you should consider using the free Sensible TableView framework. It has these kind of max object limits out of the box, plus it will generate all your UI and detail views automatically from your core data entities.